# How to approach potential collaborators via email?

Tags: publications, collaboration, research-proposal

From your experience, what are some of the best ways to approach potential collaborators via email? Specially for post-docs approaching faculty members (not to join their schools/groups) but to work on possible ideas for proposals/publications. For instance, Post-doc A who works with advisor B has a good idea for research that is very far from his advisor's field. Thus, Advisor B encouraged Post-doc A to seek other collaborators. Since meeting at conferences is not possible, for some reasons, communication via email is the method of choice. How can Post-doc A approach a faculty member with his/her idea while making sure s/he gets the right to his/her ideas?

Comment: I think "cold-calling" someone to propose such a collaboration is not usually too likely to be successful.  Can you arrange an introduction from advisor B or some other mutual acquaintance?  LinkedIn could be useful in this regard if B doesn't really know the person.  If you have no mutual connections ...  good luck!  And if you do ... good luck!

Comment: @FredDouglis thanks. But Both advisors don't know each others.

Comment: Then can you find someone else who knows both of you?